# How to use a single equation number with flalign in latex.?

Tags: mathematics

I have the following code to output an equation. I want to use a single equation number for this whole block. How can we do it?

[image: latex output]
[image: latex code]

Comment: You only have one alignmrnt column?

Comment: Could you please post a code, not a screenshot of a code?

Comment: \begin{flalign}
\tilde{A} &= A_{N,m}A_{m,m}^{-1}A_{m,N} &&\\
&=A_{N,m}U\wedge^{-1}U^TA_{N,m}^T &&\\
&=A_{N,m}U\wedge^{-1/2}\wedge^{-1/2}U^TA_{N,m}^T &&\\
&=GG^T 
    \label{nystrom_evd_approx_for_indefinite}
\end{flalign}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `*` version of the environment which has no numbering and then `\tag` the desired equation. For example if you have three equations and want a number only on the second line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{commath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign*}
        F &= ma&&\\
        a^2 &= b^2 + c^2&&\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}\\
        0 &= e^{i\pi} + 1
    \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Here `\refstepcounter{equation}` increases the value of the equation counter and also makes it accessible to `\label` and then `\tag{\theequation}` labels the equation with the current equation number.

Comment: Great !! That did the trick.. Thanks for your quick help !!

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason to change from standard centering to left alignment for a single display, so I guess you want *all* displays to be flush left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

This is some text prior to the display running to at least
cover two lines; let's add some words until they fit
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tilde{A}
&= A_{N,m} A_{m,m}^{-1} A_{m,N} \\
&= A_{N,m} U \wedge^{-1} U^T A_{N,m}^T \\
&= A_{N,m} U \wedge^{-1/2} {} \wedge^{-1/2} U^T A_{N,m}^T \\
&= GG^{T}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and some text past the display.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really* want this particular display to be flush left, but I can't imagine why, you can do as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is some text prior to the display running to at least
cover two lines; let's add some words until they fit
\begin{flalign}
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{A}
&= A_{N,m} A_{m,m}^{-1} A_{m,N} \\
&= A_{N,m} U \wedge^{-1} U^T A_{N,m}^T \\
&= A_{N,m} U \wedge^{-1/2} {} \wedge^{-1/2} U^T A_{N,m}^T \\
&= GG^{T}
\end{aligned}&&
\end{flalign}
and some text past the display.

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with a plain `aligned` environment within `equation` nested in a `fleqn` environment, defined by the `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
```

\usepackage{commath}

```
\begin{document}

    \noindent Some text. some text. Some more text. Some more text.
    \begin{fleqn}
    \begin{equation}
      \begin{aligned}
       \tilde{A} & = A_{N, m}A_{m, m}^{-1}A_{m, N} \\
      & = A_{N, m}\wedge^{-1}U^{\mathrm t} A_{N, m}^{\mathrm t} \\
      & = A_{N, m}\wedge^{-1/2}\wedge^{-1/2}U^{\mathrm t} A_{N, m}^{\mathrm t} \\
      & = GG^{\mathrm t}
            \end{aligned}%
    \label{nystrom_evd_approx_for_indefinite}
    \end{equation}
    \end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I get it.. it gives equation number in the middle.. so you dont need to specify it separately like we use tag in * environment (a solution given below by Willoughby.)

Comment: You only need a \label for crossreferences.  If you prefer the equation number aligned with the first or the last line, use the optional argument of the environment`[t]` or `[b]` (`[c]` being the default).